# Cannot install http client package in flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to add http package to my sample flutter project. However, it constantly fails.

It gives the following o/p

```
>[sample_hello_world] flutter packages get
>Running "flutter packages get" in sample_hello_world...             1.3s
>exit code 0
>[sample_hello_world] flutter packages get
>Running "flutter packages get" in sample_hello_world...             1.1s
>exit code 0
>[sample_hello_world] flutter packages get
>Running "flutter packages get" in sample_hello_world...             0.8s
>exit code 0
```

This is my pubspec.yaml

name: sample_hello_world
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.2
  http: ^0.12.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/login_icon.png

Any ideas, i/p will be appreciated.

I have tried different networks, checked for unwanted proxies. Can't get to know what is. I wrote and then tapped on the Get Packages button in Visual Studio IDE, but it never seems to load the package[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install this instead :

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

That's it , there is not an error or something, to test if everything is set up ,
maka a dart file , and import this :

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

if it shows that it's an unused package , that means that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I declare http dependence in this way. Remember to take care of your indentation

[Declaration code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krfMy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with this. Helped relaunching Android Studio and installing again.